# Ignore duplicate jobs running with at command

Tags: shell, freebsd, at-job

I'm on `Freebsd9.2`.(I have to use this operating system) I want to run multiple scripts with at command but I want to ignore running a script in a same time.

**For example:** I have 3 script files: 1.sh, 2.sh, 3.sh

I have a job to execute 1.sh at today 16:20, when I run the [at](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=at&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) command with the same time and script, the number of the jobs in `/var/at/jobs` changed to 2 jobs. I want to ignore this, but the script 2.sh can run with thw same time. Do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: lucky you that have to work with FreeBSD :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood correctly the problem, but maybe the command [lockf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lockf&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3) could help.

For example try this in one terminal:

```
$ lockf -t 0 /tmp/a.lock sleep 5
```

In another terminal run:

```
$ lockf -t 0 /tmp/a.lock echo "sleep finished"
```

In this example until the command `sleep 5` doesn't exit, if you try to run another command you will get something like:

```
lockf: /tmp/a.lock: already locked
```

A `cron` example:

```
15 4 * * * lockf -t 0 /tmp/poudriere.lock /usr/local/etc/poudriere.d/cron 12amd64 default
```

This prevents running the script/app if the lock exists, so probably you can get an idea of how you could use it with `at`